# Testing Widget with ChangeNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-provider

I do not understand how widget tests works with ChangeNotifier Provider despite all tutorials. I am beginner.

Here is the widget I need to test.

```
class SummaryScreen extends StatelessWidget {   
const SummaryScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override   
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Person> tenants = context.watch<TenantSTATE>().tenants;

    return Scaffold( 
       body: Text(tenants.length) 
    );
    }
```

Here is my test :

```
void main() async {

  testWidgets("Flutter Widget Test", (WidgetTester tester) async {

    await tester.pumpWidget(SummaryScreen());
    expect(find.widgetWithIcon(FloatingActionButton, Icons.add), findsOneWidget);

  });
}
```

I am getting this error :

> Could not find the correct Provider above this
> SummaryScreen Widget

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Add needed providers to the widget tree when calling pumpWidget, like you do it in your app, something like this:

```
await tester.pumpWidget(
  MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      Provider<Something>(create: (_) => Something()),
      Provider<SomethingElse>(create: (_) => SomethingElse()),
      Provider<AnotherThing>(create: (_) => AnotherThing()),
    ],
    child: SummaryScreen(),
  )
)
```